# Use jQuery to convert Nested Unordered Lists into Breadcrumbs

Tags: jquery, navigation, html-lists

I have a nested unordered list populated by ajax and I am looking to create breadcrumb-style navigation out of it.  The end result should be I click on any node in the list and the parent list items show up in the breadcrumb navigation.

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li class="expanded">
            <a href="#" id="1122">Root Group</a>
        </li>
        <ul>
            <li class="expanded">
                <a href="#" id="1126">Northeast US</a>
            </li>
            <ul>
                <li class="collapsed">
                    <a href="#" id="1127">Massachusetts</a>
                </li>
                <ul style="display: none; ">
                    <li class="expanded node">
                        <a href="#" id="1128">Mansfield-Foxboro</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="expanded node">
                        <a href="#" id="1129">North Attleboro</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="expanded">
                    <a href="#" id="1144">New Hampshire</a>
                </li>
                <ul>
                    <li class="expanded node">
                        <a href="#" id="1145">Manchester</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            <li class="expanded">
                <a href="#" id="1181">Mid-Atlantic US</a>
            </li>
            <ul>
                <li class="expanded">
                    <a href="#" id="1182">New York City</a>
                </li>
                <ul>
                    <li class="expanded node">
                        <a href="#" id="1183">Time Square</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I click on New York City and I get:
Root Group > Mid-Atlantic US > New York City

I click on North Attleboro and I get:
Root Group > Northeast US > Massachusetts > North Attleboro

Is there a way to build this path using jQuery traversal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from the clicked `<a>` element, use [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to match the `<ul>` elements in its ancestor chain, then apply [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to the result to obtain the immediately preceding `<li>` elements.

From there, you can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to match the `<a>` elements within the list items. If you [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) the clicked hyperlink itself to the result set, you will have a jQuery object containing all the hyperlinks in the path, in the proper order.

Now you only have to use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to build an array of inner text values from the `<a>` elements, along with [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate a path string. The end result is something like:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var path = $(this).parents("ul").prev("li").find("a").add(this)
        .map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get().join(" > ");

    // Do something with 'path'...
});
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAjjj/).

Comment: This is perfect - I didn't want to introduce any unnecessary markup and this finds the exact set without depending on the .node class either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the `<li>` ascendants of the clicked `<li>` with the following code:

```
$('li').bind('click', function () {
    var $ascendants = $(this).parents('ul'),
        output      = [];
    $.each($ascendants, function (index, value) {
        output.push($(value).children('li').not('.node').children('a:first').text());
    });
    //output is not an array of all the text within parent li tags of the clicked li tag
    console.log(output);
});
```

This finds all the ascendant `<ul>` tags of the `<li>` that was clicked, the iterates through them, selecting the text from non `.node` `<li>`'s.

Here is a jsfiddle that outputs an array you can use for your breadcrums: http://jsfiddle.net/rE9x8/1/

Answer (score 0):

I just crudely navigated the structure:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var current = $(this),string = [];current.parent().parent().parent().attr('id') != 'list';current = current.parent().parent().prev().children('a'))
        string.push(current.text());
    string.push(current.text());
    alert(string.reverse().join('>'));
});
```